# Plot data behind 2D plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a fairly complex plotting problem that i thought it would be interesting to get a solution to. Say i have two plots, number 1:

This plot was created using plotyy.

And number 2:

This plot was created using plot3(x, y, z, '.')

Now, the complex part is i want to take plot number 2, watermark it and put it behind plot number 1. Which would result in something like this:

Effectively what i want to show is that plot 1 is made from data that looks like plot 2. Now i haven't been able to find how to do this so it may not even be possible, but if it can be done then it would be a great tutorial to have on stack overflow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this but it will take some work to get the axes formatted so they look nice.

What you need to do is put one `axes` object on top of another `axes`; however, to prevent the top `axes` from occluding the bottom one you need to set the `'Color'` property of the top `axes` object to `'none'`.

Here is an example script that generates something similar to what you are looking for

```
f = figure;
axes();
x = rand(100,3)*3 + 3;
plot3(x(:,1), x(:,2), x(:,3),'.');

axes('Color', 'none');
x = -5:5;
y = x.^2;
line(x,y, 'Color', 'r', 'LineWidth', 2);
```

Here is the resulting figure:
[image]

If you don't like how this works out you can try to project your 3D data into 2D and then draw that projection as an image behind your lines.  Here is a [link to a discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/169417) about how you might go about creating the 2D projection.